# Looking for something like a TestFlow analogous to TestSink and TestSource

Tags: scala, sockets, akka, akka-stream

I am writing a class that takes a Flow (representing a kind of socket) as a constructor argument and that allows to send messages and wait for the respective answers asynchronously by returning a `Future`. Example:

```
class SocketAdapter(underlyingSocket: Flow[String, String, _]) {
    def sendMessage(msg: MessageType): Future[ResponseType]
}
```

This is not necessarily trivial because there may be other messages in the socket stream that are irrelevant, so some filtering is required.

In order to test the class I need to provide something like a "TestFlow" analogous to `TestSink` and `TestSource`. In fact I can create a flow by combining both. However, the problem is that I only obtain the actual probes upon materialization and materialization happens inside the class under test.

The problem is similar to the one I described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50188029/302793). My problem would be solved if I could materialize the flow first and then pass it to a client to connect to it. Again, I'm thinking about using `MergeHub` and `BroadcastHub` and again I see the problem that the resulting stream would behave differently because it is not linear anymore.

Maybe I misunderstood how a `Flow` is supposed to be used. In order to feed messages into the flow when `sendMessage()` is called, I need a certain kind of `Source` anyway. Maybe a `Source.actorRef(...)` or `Source.queue(...)`, so I could pass in the `ActorRef` or `SourceQueue` directly. However, I'd prefer if this choice was up to the `SocketAdapter` class. Of course, this applies to the `Sink` as well.

It feels like this is a rather common case when working with streams and sockets. If it is not possible to create a "TestFlow" like I need it, I'm also happy with some advice on how to improve my design and make it better testable.

**Update:** I browsed through the documentation and found `SourceRef` and `SinkRef`. It looks like these could solve my problem but I'm not sure yet. Is it reasonable to use them in my case or are there any drawbacks, e.g. different behaviour in the test compared to production where there are no such refs?

Answer (score 0):

**Indirect Answer**

The nature of your question suggests a design flaw which you are bumping into at testing time.  The answer below does not address the issue in your question, but it demonstrates how to avoid the situation altogether.

**Don't Mix Business Logic with Akka Code**

Presumably you need to test your `Flow` because you have mixed a substantial amount of logic into the materialization.  Lets assume you are using raw sockets for your IO.  Your question suggests that your flow looks like:

```
val socketFlow : Flow[String, String, _] = {
  val socket = new Socket(...)

  //business logic for IO
}
```

You need a complicated test framework for your Flow because your Flow itself is also complicated.

Instead, you should separate out the logic into an independent function that has no akka dependencies:

```
type MessageProcessor = MessageType => ResponseType

object BusinessLogic {
  val createMessageProcessor : (Socket) => MessageProcessor = {
    //business logic for IO
  } 
}
```

Now your flow can be very simple:

```
val socket : Socket = new Socket(...)

val socketFlow = Flow.map(BusinessLogic.createMessageProcessor(socket))
```

As a result: your unit testing can exclusively work with `createMessageProcessor`, there's no need to test akka Flow because it is a simple veneer around the complicated logic that is tested independently.

**Don't Use Streams For Concurrency Around 1 Element**

The other big problem with your design is that `SocketAdapter` is using a stream to process just 1 message at a time.  This is incredibly wasteful and unnecessary (you're trying to kill a mosquito with a tank).

Given the separated business logic your adapter becomes much simpler and independent of akka:

```
class SocketAdapter(messageProcessor : MessageProcessor) {
  def sendMessage(msg: MessageType): Future[ResponseType] = Future {
    messageProcessor(msg)
  }
}
```

Note how easy it is to use `Future` in some instances and `Flow` in other scenarios depending on the need.  This comes from the fact that the business logic is independent of any concurrency framework.

Comment: Thanks you for your extensive answer. In fact I am not testing the flow but the adapter. I need something like a mock for the flow. The flow represents a JSON-RPC socket that receives JSON messages with ids and responds with JSON objects having corresponding ids. I want to test that the adapter waits for the respective response and completes the future (+ error handling). So the adapter is at the intersection of the akka domain and the rest of the application. Responses may come in any order so I cannot extract a type `MessageType => ResponseType`.

Comment: @lex82 That fits into my general point: if your `SocketAdapter` took something less complicated that a `Flow` then it would be easier to test.  Example: if you used a `MessageProcessor` as in my demonstration then you could write a test processor: `val testMessageProcessor : MessageProcessor = _ => "Foo"`.  Now you can test SocketAdapter with a processor that always returns `"Foo"` as the value...

Comment: Sorry, I don't really get it. I have to use a `Flow` since I am using a web socket that is represented as a flow.   At some point there has to be a component that sees the flow and translates to methods returning futures. This is what I am trying to do with the adapter. Or is there something generic I can use? I tried to keep the flow simple by only adding marshalling for my message and response case classes.

Comment: I added an answer that shows a solution that solves my problem. Maybe not in the nicest way, but I feel something like this could be useful in other circumstances as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with using `SinkRef` and `SourceRef`:

```
object TestFlow {

  def withProbes[In, Out](implicit actorSystem: ActorSystem,
                                   actorMaterializer: ActorMaterializer)
    :(Flow[In, Out, _], TestSubscriber.Probe[In], TestPublisher.Probe[Out]) = {
    val f = Flow.fromSinkAndSourceMat(TestSink.probe[In], TestSource.probe[Out])
            (Keep.both)

    val ((sinkRefFuture, (inProbe, outProbe)), sourceRefFuture) =
      StreamRefs.sinkRef[In]()
        .viaMat(f)(Keep.both)
        .toMat(StreamRefs.sourceRef[Out]())(Keep.both)
        .run()

    val sinkRef = Await.result(sinkRefFuture, 3.seconds)
    val sourceRef = Await.result(sourceRefFuture, 3.seconds)

    (Flow.fromSinkAndSource(sinkRef, sourceRef), inProbe, outProbe)
  }

}
```

This gives me a flow I can completely control with the two probes but I can pass it to a client that connects source and sink later, so it seems to solve my problem.

The resulting `Flow` should only be used once, so it differs from a regular `Flow` that is rather a flow blueprint and can be materialized several times. However, this restriction applies to the web socket flow I am mocking anyway, as described [here](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/client-side/websocket-support.html).

The only issue I still have is that some warnings are logged when the `ActorSystem` terminates after the test. This seems to be due to the indirection introduced by the `SinkRef` and `SourceRef`.

**Update:** I found a better solution without `SinkRef` and `SourceRef` by using `mapMaterializedValue()`:

```
def withProbesFuture[In, Out](implicit actorSystem: ActorSystem,
                                       ec: ExecutionContext)
  : (Flow[In, Out, _],
         Future[(TestSubscriber.Probe[In], TestPublisher.Probe[Out])]) = {
    val (sinkPromise, sourcePromise) =
        (Promise[TestSubscriber.Probe[In]], Promise[TestPublisher.Probe[Out]])

    val flow =
      Flow
        .fromSinkAndSourceMat(TestSink.probe[In], TestSource.probe[Out])(Keep.both)
        .mapMaterializedValue { case (inProbe, outProbe) =>
          sinkPromise.success(inProbe)
          sourcePromise.success(outProbe)
          ()
        }

    val probeTupleFuture = sinkPromise.future
        .flatMap(sink => sourcePromise.future.map(source => (sink, source)))
    (flow, probeTupleFuture)
  }
```

When the class under test materializes the flow, the `Future` is completed and I receive the test probes.